# Download and encode image in base64 using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, base64

lets say i have a URL given. I would like to:

1) download it and convert to base64
2) upload it to some key/value storage (as text)
3) download it from key/value storage (with text/plain mimetype), reencode it from base64, display it.

Best Regards

Comment: ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.btoa ) &
( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.atob ) can be used to encode and decode base64, but I'm not so sure about the other parts.

Comment: For #2 and #3, check Web Storage in MDN.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still searching for downloading images and encoding them in base64 string, I recently find this kind of `outdated` method but really reliable. The advantage is that it's pure Javascript so there is no need to install any external library. I previously tried using fetch and axios but for some reason the encoded string was not in a correct format.

NB: If you are encoding this image to send it to an API, some of them require to delete the leading data type including the `,` at the start of the encoded string.

```
function toDataURL (url,  callback) {
    const xhRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhRequest.onload = function () {
        const reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            callback(reader.result)
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(xhRequest.response)
    }
    xhRequest.open('GET', url)
    xhRequest.responseType = 'blob'
    xhRequest.send()
}

const URL = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f7/Stack_Overflow_logo.png"
const logCallback = (base64image) => {
    // Base64 encoded string with leading data type like
    // data:image/png;base64,RAW_ENCODED_DATA______
    console.log(base64image)
}
toDataURL(URL, logCallback)
```